# Oracle SQL -Retrieving Master and Child's data

Tags: oracle

I have the below mentioned table structure.

Master-Child Table:

```
Master_Job_Id    Child_Job_Id
M1                  C1
M1                  C2
```

Amount Table(This table contains the details of Child and Master Job Ids):

```
Job_Id      Rate_Id         Amount
M1              R1            50
C1              R1            10
C2              R2            25
```

Rate Table

```
Rate_Id     Lang_Id
R1              L1
R2              L2
```

Here M1 Job Id has two Childs C1 and C2. I would like to frame a query which would provide me the below data:

```
Job_Id      Lang_Id         Amount
M1              L1              60(Since M1 has two L1 values - that of M1 and C1, the amounts are added so 60 should come)
M1              L2              25(Here M1 has only one L2 value so the total amount value is 25)
```

Any help on this is much appreciated.

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT t.master_job_id,r.Lang_Id,sum(a.amount)
FROM Master_Child t
INNER JOIN amount a
 ON(a.job_id in(t.master_job_id,t.child_job_id))
INNER JOIN Rate r
 ON(a.rate_id = r.rate_id)
GROUP BY t.master_job_id,r.lang_id
```

Comment: After changing  ON(a.rate_id = a.rate_id) to  ON(a.rate_id = r.rate_id) its working correctly. Thank you Mr.Florin

Comment: Oh,yea, typo... No problem:)